# Have an airbnb dataset and need to determine which hosts have multiple apartments on the same location using the join-function

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, inner-join

Based on an airbnb dataset I need to figure out which hosts have multiple rooms on the same location.

I have two tables: airbnb and airbnb_locations

The first six rows of the airbnb table look like this:

```
host_id    room_id    latitude    longitude
2536       2318       47.61       -122.29
35749      4291       47.68       -122.31
8993       5682       47.52       -122.35
14942      6606       47.65       -122.33
30559      9419       47.55       -122.31
30832      9460       47.60       -122.32
```

The first six rows of the airbnb_locations table look like this:

```
room_id    latitude    longitude
2318       47.61       -122.29
4291       47.68       -122.31
5682       47.52       -122.35
6606       47.65       -122.33
9419       47.55       -122.31
9460       47.60       -122.32
```

So the only difference between the tables is the host_id attribute.

This was my first attempt:

```
select distinct t1.host_id, t1.room_id, t1.latitude, t1.longitude
from airbnb t1 inner join airbnb_locations t2
where t1.latitude = t2.latitude
and t1.longitude = t2.longitude
and t1.room_id <> t2.room_id
```

The problem with this code is that it also yields rooms belonging to different hosts on the same location. I have tried grouping the rooms by host, but this gives me wrong results for some reason.

A solution could be adding the host_id attribute to airbnb_locations and then:

```
select distinct t1.host_id, t1.room_id, t1.latitude, t1.longitude
from airbnb t1 inner join airbnb_locations t2
where t1.host_id = t2.host_id
and t1.latitude = t2.latitude
and t1.longitude = t2.longitude
and t1.room_id <> t2.room_id
```

But then I'm left with two identical tables and I'm not really sure that was the point of this exercise. So I'm curious if I have missed an obvious solution to solving the problem based on the two initial tables using the join-function?

Comment: What type of SQL? And can you provide an example of your schema with some sample data?

Comment: I have edited the post so it includes the tables. I'm completely new to SQL but I'm using databricks, so my guess is sparkSQL. I've added it to the keywords.

Comment: What are your expected results, given your sample data?

Comment: Right now the result is just list of all of the attribute values for the cases where a host has several rooms at one location.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want aggregation:

```
select a.host_id, a.latitude, a.longitude
from airbnb a
group by a.host_id, a.latitude, a.longitude
having count(*) > 1;
```

This actually returns the locations.  If you really just want the hosts, then this is a very rare time when `select distinct` is appropriate with `group by`:

```
select distinct a.host_id
from airbnb a
group by a.host_id, a.latitude, a.longitude
having count(*) > 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to do a `JOIN` here. You can probably just `GROUP BY` the host_id, latitude, and longitude, and return only the hosts that have multiple rooms. Your query might look something like this:

```
SELECT 
    host_id
    ,latitude
    ,longitude
FROM airbnb
GROUP BY
    host_id
    ,latitude
    ,longitude
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT room_id) > 1
```